# Joomla 3 reCaptcha validation

Tags: joomla, recaptcha

I have a simple custom form in Joomla 3.6 that I have added reCaptcha to successfully. However, I am struggling with validating this.

After a few web searches, I can up with the following code:

```
$joomla_captcha = JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha');
if ( $joomla_captcha != '0') {
    $jpost = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post; 
    $reCaptcha = $jpost->get("g-recaptcha-response");
    $dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance(); 
    $captcha_response = $dispatcher->trigger('onCheckAnswer', $reCaptcha);
}

if ( ! $captcha_response[0] ) { 
    die("Invalid Captcha");     
}
```

However, the form is passing whether the captcha is done or not.

What changes do I need to make to pick up whether the captcha was passed or not?

The form is really basic and I am loathe to install yet another component just for this validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it appears I hit a brick wall in trying to find a "Joomla" way to do this that calls on inbuilt API methods.

Since I am only using Google reCaptcha, I found on [Google's site](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) that the "g-recaptcha-response" field is empty if the captcha challenge has not been completed and not empty if correctly completed.

So, for Google reCaptcha, I need to test the "g-recaptcha-response" field and my code example becomes:

```
$joomla_captcha = JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha');
if ( $joomla_captcha != '0') {
    $jpost = JFactory::getApplication()->input->post; 
    $reCaptcha = $jpost->get("g-recaptcha-response");
}

if ( isset( $reCaptcha ) && empty( $reCaptcha ) { 
    die("Invalid Captcha");     
}
```

This is obviously limited to Google reCaptcha and would have been nice to query the Joomla API Layer instead to allow flexibility but good enough.

**Edit**

The following Joomla API calls will return "true" or "false" into $completed indicating whether the captcha passed or not

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig()->get('captcha');
$captcha = JCaptcha::getInstance($config);
$completed = $captcha->CheckAnswer();

if ($completed === false) {
    die("Invalid Captcha");
}
```

Preferable to the earlier approach as will be able to work with other captcha plugins that may be added to Joomla.

Comment: `Warning: Missing argument 1 for Joomla\CMS\Captcha\Captcha::checkAnswer()` https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/23619/12352

Comment: @mickmackusa, There is a "bug" in the Joomla code as the ReCaptcha plugin does not require the argument but the inbuilt captcha class method does. This generates the warning in PHP 7. Workaround if passing the argument from form input is to test if this is empty and pass a deliberate invalid value. Would have been nice for the guy in the other link to have attributed this as the source of his code!

Comment: Please go add your 2-cents.  (see user's previous question as well -- he's been grappling with this task for a short while)

Comment: ...I was hoping you would help.  Okay.

Comment: Would have liked to but have nothing to add. Code above works for me and looks like he has found a solution in any case.